# Time complexity of numerical finite differences

Tags: finite-difference, numerics, complexity

I have a function $f:\mathbb R^N\to \mathbb R$ and I would like to compute all the partial derivatives of $f$ w.r.t. the $N$ input. What is the computational complexity using the (ones-sided) finite difference method $\big(\text{derivative of f w.r.t. x}\sim\frac {f(x+\epsilon)-f(x)}{\epsilon}\big)$ using the $O( \ )$-notation? Could you also provide an explanation of that?

Comment: You are dividing by a vector, aren't you?

Comment: Also, what is the complexity of evaluating $f$?

Comment: @nicoguaro why dividing by a vector? the complexity of f is not known but I suppose that does not impact on the general order of the complexity. Let's say that the general order is n, if $f$ embed a sum, a multiplication and some other computation, the order will be always n.. it seems to me..

Comment: @nicoguaro is right here. You are confused here I think. If $f$ is a function that takes a vector $x$, you can't evaluate this expression $\frac{f(x+\epsilon)-f(x)}{\epsilon}$ cause it seems $\epsilon$ is also a vector. Unless, you are also confused and mixed up the notations here, which needs to be clarified. Also, you **can't** say I don't care about time-complexity of $f$ cause any finite difference method to approximate the derivatives needs to evaluate $f$ at some points in the space and final time-complexity depends on $f$ for **sure**.

Comment: You meant to write $f(x+\epsilon e_i)$ where $e_i$ is the $i$th unit vector.

Answer (score 7):

As pointed out in the comments, the cost of evaluating $f$ is critical, and in most practical cases will be the dominant cost.  Lets suppose it takes $C$ operations to evaluate $f$.  For nontrivial functions, $C$ will be at least $\mathcal{O}(N)$ just from using the $N$ arguments.

Also pointed out in the comments, the finite difference formula you have does not make sense for a function that maps a vector to a scalar.  If you are looking to approximate the entire gradient vector $\nabla f$ with finite differences, you can use the approximation

$$
\nabla f(x) = \begin{bmatrix}
\frac{f(x + \epsilon e_1) - f(x)}{\epsilon} & \frac{f(x + \epsilon e_2) - f(x)}{\epsilon} & \cdots & \frac{f(x + \epsilon e_N) - f(x)}{\epsilon}
\end{bmatrix} + \mathcal{O}(\epsilon^2)
$$

where $e_i$ is the $i$-th canonical basis vector for $\mathbb{R}^N$.  There are $N+1$ calls to $f$ here along with $N$ subtractions and divisions so the cost is $\mathcal{O}(C N)$.

In many cases a gradient is multiplied by a vector to get a directional derivative $\nabla f(x) \cdot v$.  If this is the case, the following approximation is more efficient:

$$
\nabla f(x) \cdot v = \frac{f(x + \epsilon v) - f(x)}{\epsilon} + \mathcal{O}(\epsilon^2).
$$

Now there are just two function evaluations and a cost of $\mathcal{O}(C)$.